# Tracer not getting initialized through constructor when running Junit test case in Spring Boot

Tags: junit, spring-test

I am trying to run a Junit test from spring boot and added the AvailabilityController with @InjectMocks. Controller has a constructor which takes Tracer(brave.Tracer) as one of the argument. So have added TraceAutoConfiguration.class in the @ContextConfiguration of the Junit class.

@ContextConfiguration(classes = { AvailabilityController.class, TraceAutoConfiguration.class })

Constructor in the controller class

```
    @Autowired
   public AvailabilityController(AvailabilityService availService,
    Tracer tracer) {
this.availService= availService;
this.tracer = tracer;
this.responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    }
```

And there is getTrace method which is invoked from the controller class.

```
private String getTraceId() {
    Span currentSpan = this.tracer.currentSpan();
    return currentSpan.context().traceIdString();
}
```

When I try to run the Junit, getting Null pointer in the line this.tracer.currentSpan(); as this.tracer is null. What should be done to initialize the tracer when running Junit. It runs fine when running the main application

Tried adding the TraceAutoConfiguration and Tracer in the Junit test class as Autowired, but still it didnt help resolved the Null Pointer exception